# Caps lock key won't switch between Hebrew and alternative characters

Tags: localization

I am very new to Ubuntu and I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 in English and than added Hebrew to it (as a second language).

When I switch from English to Hebrew via Left-Alt+Shift (The combination I defined) I can use the language itself just fine but I can't switch between **it** and universal-characters\ Key-alternatives via **Caps lock** key (as I can with all versions of Windows).

In Hebrew keyboards we use Caps lock for alternative usage of some keys. For example:

```
ף=;
ת=,
ץ=.
```

*Note: Both characters from each side of the equality mark are initiated by the same key in typical English-Hebrew keyboards - Depends on Caps lock.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed Hebrew keyboard, tried to enter ף ץ ת and ;,. using a Keyboard Layout Chart and did not encounter a problem. To show the chart, in status bar click the language icon > Keyboard Layout Chart.

If you need to display character from right bottom corner of the button on this chart, use combination with the Alt button on the right side <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>. For example <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> will give you comma: ",".

This chart will also tell you what characters will be displayed after using <kbd>Shift</kbd> (upper left side).

[image]

To activate alternative keys, go to main Ubuntu `Settings` > `Keyboard` and in the `Shortcuts` tab under `Typing` set `Alternative Character Key` to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This problem seems to me to be only Physical-keyboard related... In all humbleness, the most general and efficient way of solving it will be a way to use Caps lock to activate the alternative keys for the Hebrew-on state...

Comment: @benos Hi, so I edited my answer with instructions to set Alternative Character Key to Caps Lock.

Comment: MIke, I encounter something very wried: From the moment I went to System settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typing and setted the ACK to Caps lock --- I could no longer use Caps lock with my keyboard... Even it's light on the keyboard itself didn't light in all the times I clicked on it... But as you can tell for now I've brought the ACK to "Disabled" again... Something here is wired indeed...

Comment: @benos Looks like you found a bug, because I have same problem here, once you set the Alternative Character Keys to Caps Lock, Caps Lock is out   of the game, stops responding even if Hebrew is uninstalled.

Comment: Oh WOW... Well, since I'm so new in the business, can you please advice me where is the best place for me to report this? Or would you like to have the honor yourself?

Comment: I think best way is to ask another question on this forum specific only to this problem with Alternative Character Key and Caps Lock being totally disabled, and see what happens when other more experienced Ubuntu users  try to reproduce the same problem and rule out obvious mistakes. I can do that for you with uploading screenshot and explaining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick, at least for the Hebrew points (this is the only thing I used <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> in Windows for), is to use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> pressed together with some number. For example, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> yields ֱ
In my opinion, it is easier than in the Windows layout (one key instead of two)

Also, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+ <kbd>ש</kbd> = ₪ , unlike in the Windows layout